# Why finetuning MLP model on a small dataset, still keeps the test accuracy same as pre-trained weights?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have designed a simple MLP model trained on 6k data samples.

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_dim=92, hidden_dim = 150, num_classes=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        #self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1)

        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.num_classes),

        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layers(x)
        return x
```

and the model has been instantiated

```
model = MLP(input_dim=input_dim, hidden_dim=hidden_dim, num_classes=num_classes).to(device)

optimizer = Optimizer.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=1e-4)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

and the hyperparameters:

```
num_epoch = 300   # 200e3//len(train_loader)
learning_rate = 1e-3
batch_size = 64
device = torch.device("cuda")
SEED = 42
torch.manual_seed(42)
```

My implementation mostly follows [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199036/pytorch-nn-not-as-good-as-sklearn-mlp). I save the model as pre-trained weights `model_weights.pth`.

The accuracy of `model` on the test dataset is `96.80%`.

Then, I have another 50 samples (in `finetune_loader`) that I am trying to fine-tune the model on these 50 samples:

```
model_finetune = MLP()
model_finetune.load_state_dict(torch.load('model_weights.pth'))
model_finetune.to(device)
model_finetune.train()
# train the network
for t in tqdm(range(num_epoch)):
  for i, data in enumerate(finetune_loader, 0):
    #def closure():
      # Get and prepare inputs
      inputs, targets = data
      inputs, targets = inputs.float(), targets.long()
      inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)
      
      # Zero the gradients
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      # Perform forward pass
      outputs = model_finetune(inputs)
      # Compute loss
      loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
      # Perform backward pass
      loss.backward()
      #return loss
      optimizer.step()     # a

model_finetune.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs2 = model_finetune(test_data)
    #predicted_labels = outputs.squeeze().tolist()

    _, preds = torch.max(outputs2, 1)
    prediction_test = np.array(preds.cpu())
    accuracy_test_finetune = accuracy_score(y_test, prediction_test)
    accuracy_test_finetune
    
    Output: 0.9680851063829787
```

The accuracy remains the same as before fine-tuning the model to 50 samples, I checked, and the output probabilities are also the same.

What could be the reason? Am I making some mistakes in the code for fine-tuning?

Comment: Can you check whether the weights change at all?

Comment: "The accuracy remains the same as before fine-tuning the model to 50 samples". does it mean that during training the epochs look exactly as during the last epoch in training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-initialize the optimizer with the new model -- the model_finetune object. Currently, as I see it in your code, it seems to still use the optimizer which is initialized with your old model weights -- model.parameters().